# Angularjs $cookieProvider unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

I use a custom authentication service to store my authentication token, authToken. This stores the received user profile into a client side cache with $cookieStorage.put() method. When i run, i get the unrecognized provider error:

authToken:

```html
appModule.factory('authToken',['$cookieStorage',
    function($cookieStorage) {
        var cachedStorage;
        return {
            setToken: function(token) {
                cachedStorage = token;
                $cookieStorage.put('userToken', token);
            },
            getToken: function() {
                if (!cachedStorage) {
                    cachedStorage = $cookieStorage.get('userToken');
                }
            },
            isAuthenticated: function() {
                return !!this.getToken();
            }
        };
    }]);
```

where i use it:

```html
appModule.controller('AuthenticationController',
    function ($scope, accountRepository,authToken) {
        $scope.login = function(credentials) {
            var profile = accountRepository.login(credentials);
            profile.success(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    var userData = {
                        username: data.username,
                        firstName: data.firstName,
                        lastName: data.lastName,
                        isLogged: true
                    }
                    alert('success', 'OK', 'You are now registered' +                     userData.firstName);
                    authToken.setToken(userData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

the ngCookie module is inserted into appModule, this works fine because i have used it before.

Comment: Isn't it $cookieStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `$cookieStore` not `$cookieStorage`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore